# Recently installed Linux Bash Shell (Ubuntu installed) not showing my files on my windows computer

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, terminal

I've ran into a problem when trying to use an installed Linux bash shell instead of my Windows command prompt. I can't get my computer files to show on my Ubuntu terminal, even though when I repeat the same actions on my windows command prompt they seem to work.

[image: Windows Command Prompt file directory search result]
[image: Ubuntu Terminal file directory search result]

I'm thinking there must be an issue with my installation, possibly I need to do a few more steps to get it to work like my regular command prompt terminal, but I'm not sure how to do this currently. I've added some screenshots above for additional context of me not finding my files in Ubuntu but being able to find them through windows command prompt.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your linux home directory is most likely located outside of your windows user's home directory.

Use windows search to look for one of your ubuntu files (for example git_101) to determine where is your ubuntu home directory in relation to windows file system.

This can vary depending on how you installed ubuntu, but you might be able to access your windows filesystem via the `/mnt` directory as well. You can check that by running `ls -lah /mnt`.

Comment: thank you i realized this yesterday, just did /mnt and it started working